# Unit testing AngularJS promises with ES6

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to test an async method in an AngularJS service that calls another async function internally using Jasmine and Karma.

Here's how my service looks like:

```
export default class SearchUserAPI {

  constructor(BaseService, $q) {
    this.q_ = $q;
    this.service_ = BaseService;
  }

  isActive(email) {
    const params = {'email': email};

    return this.service_.getUser(params).then(isActive => {
      // This part cannot be reached.
      console.log('Is Active');
      // I need to test the following logic.
      return isActive ? true : this.q_.reject(`User ${email} is not active.`);
    });
  }
}
```

And here's how my test looks like:

```
import SearchUserApi from './api.service';

let service,
    mockedService,
    $q;

const email = 'chuck.norris@openx.com';
const expectedParams = {email: email};

describe('Search API unit tests', function() {

  beforeEach(inject(_$q_ => {
    $q = _$q_;
    mockedService = {};

    service = new SearchUserApi(mockedService, $q);
  }));

  // This test passes, but it doesn't reach the logging statement in main method.
  it('is verifying that Chuck Norris should be active', () => {
    // Trying to mock getUser() to return a promise that resolves to true.
    mockedService.getUser = jasmine.createSpy('getUser').and.returnValue($q.when(true));

    service.isActive(email).then(result => {
      // The following should fail, but since this part is called asynchronously and tests end before this expression is called, I never get an error for this.
      expect(result).toBe(false);
    });
    // This test passes, but I'm not too sure how I can verify that isActive(email) returns true for user.
    expect(mockedService.getUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedParams);
  });
});
```

I see in a lot of tutorials, they talk about using $scope and apply to see if a scope variable has been changed. But in my case, I'm not manipulating any instance(scope) variable to use $scope.apply().

Any idea how I can make the test to wait for my async calls to be resolved before they end?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to go through the async method. All I have to do was to inject *$rootScope* and use *$rootScope*.$digest() after I call the async method, even if I'm not touching scope variables inside my test.

Comment: It is not async. $q promises are synchronous, but depend on digest and require it to be triggered manually. Check https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers for easing this task.